# Nested resolution

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac

Say I have:

```
ProductA
ProductB

ProductScreen

ProductAScreen1 : ProductScreen
ProductAScreen2 : ProductScreen

ProductBScreen1 : ProductScreen
ProductBScreen2 : ProductScreen
```

How can I set it up so that I register the screens locally to the product? So when I am in ProductA and passing IEnumerable it doesn't resolve ProductB's screens?

I thought this would be achievable using something like the lifetime scope, but it doesn't appear I understood it correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lifetime scope is used to control instance lifetime. You are talking about controlling selection. For that, you should look at [the metadata features](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Metadata) in Autofac.

Using metadata, you can "tag" each product screen, indicating which product it belongs to:

```
builder.Register(c => new ProductAScreen1()).As<ProductScreen>()
    .WithMetadata<IProductScreenMetadata>(m =>
        m.For(am => am.ProductType, typeof(ProductA)));
builder.Register(c => new ProductAScreen2()).As<ProductScreen>()
    .WithMetadata<IProductScreenMetadata>(m =>
        m.For(am => am.ProductType, typeof(ProductA)));

builder.Register(c => new ProductBScreen1()).As<ProductScreen>()
    .WithMetadata<IProductScreenMetadata>(m =>
        m.For(am => am.ProductType, typeof(ProductB)));
builder.Register(c => new ProductBScreen2()).As<ProductScreen>()
    .WithMetadata<IProductScreenMetadata>(m =>
        m.For(am => am.ProductType, typeof(ProductB)));
```

Next, you can take a dependency on a `IEnumerable<Lazy<ProductScreen, IProductScreenMetadata>>` and resolve screens according to product type:

```
var productScreens = _screens.WHere(a => a.Metadata.ProductType == typeof(ProductA));
```

**Update:** for completeness, here is a simpler solution using [the Keyed approach](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/TypedNamedAndKeyedServices). First, registration is much simpler:

```
builder.RegisterType<ProductAScreen1>().Keyed<ProductScreen>(typeof(ProductA));
builder.RegisterType<ProductAScreen2>().Keyed<ProductScreen>(typeof(ProductA));
builder.RegisterType<ProductBScreen1>().Keyed<ProductScreen>(typeof(ProductB));
builder.RegisterType<ProductBScreen2>().Keyed<ProductScreen>(typeof(ProductB));
```

To resolve a collection of keyed services we'll have to take a dependency on the `IIndex<,>` type:

```
public class SomeService    
{
    private IEnumerable<ProductScreen>> _screens;
    public SomeService(IIndex<Type, IEnumerable<ProductScreen>> screens)
    {
        _screens = screens;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var screensForProductA = _screens[typeof(ProductA)];
    }
}
```

**Note:** for the curious: instead of hardcoding the type registrations, here's how you can do a "by convention" registration:

```
var assembly = ...;
var productTypes = ...;  // a collection of all the product types

foreach(var productType in productTypes)
{
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
        .Where(t => typeof(ProductScreen).IsAssignableFrom(t))
        .Where(t => t.Name.StartsWith(productType.Name))
        .Keyed<ProductScreen>(productType);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. That seems like a good option. I tried that, along with registering it using .Keyed().  They both seem like decent solutions.

Comment: Great, and yes, Keyed is easier in this scenario. Was too focused on the metadata stuff that I forgot all about it :)